# Angular : How to concat id and name in option value

Tags: angular, ngfor

I have an `*ngFor options`,

```
<select class="form-control" formControlName="industry">
      <option *ngFor="let industry of industries" [value]="industry._id  industry.name_en">{{industry.name_en}}</option>
</select>
```

What I want is both the `id` and `name_en` in option value because I need to split it back into the component.

**Or**

Is there any other way to get both value and text of options using Angular?

My angular current version is **4.4.4**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you can concat the two variables using `+`

```
<select class="form-control" formControlName="industry">
      <option *ngFor="let industry of industries" [value]="industry._id+industry.name_en">{{industry.name_en}}</option>
  </select>
```

Comment: It works, I add a few things `[value]="industry._id+'__'+industry.name_en"` in case of someone need it.

Comment: Okey Good luck bro :)

Answer (score 0):

I am using Angular 7 for my project, I am generating dynamic fields in form, so I was in need to define name of each control with index, so I found the following.

```
<div class="campform" *ngFor="let condition of conditionArray; let i = index">
   <div class="clr-col-4 gutterpadl gutterpadr">
      <input type="text" name="value{{i}}" ngModel class="borderfield" placeholder="Enter Value">
   </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Can you try and use String Interpolation there

```
<option *ngFor="let industry of industries" [value]="industry._id +industry.name_en">{{industry.name_en}}</option>
```

Comment: sorry my bad some thing like `[value]="industry._id +industry.name_en"` will work fine or even this `option *ngFor="#n of names" [attr.value]="n+2">{{n}}</option>`